# Templatetag not working in Django 4.2 template IF condition

Tags: django

I have a Django 4.2 project. For an extra Templatetag I created this simple_tag.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def user_help(context):
    # True if HELP is ON for user
    u = context['request'].user

    if u.needs_help:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

In the HTML template, I try to **catch that Tag in an IF statement**, to display help to the user, if needed, like this:

```
<p>{% user_help %}</p>
{% if user_help %}
<h2>Some help text</h2>
{% endif %}
```

Although the p-statement shows **True** in the rendered template, the **If condition** part of the template is **not** shown...?

What am I getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django templates have a distinction between variable names and template tags, so you can not just use a template tag in an `if` condition. You need to store it in a helper variable:

```
<p>{% user_help as uh %}{{ uh }}</p>
{% if uh %}
  <h2>Some help text</h2>
{% endif %}
```

That being said, I don't really see why you need a template tag for this, this is equivalent to:

```
<p>{{ user.needs_help }}</p>
{% if user.needs_help %}
  <h2>Some help text</h2>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: True on both accounts :)
Sometimes, I think to complicated, I guess :)
Thanks!!!